# EXC_AD_ACCESS on good string

Tags: macos, cocoa, variadic-functions

I log an entry using my own log function:

```
if(drive1SandboxBookmark)dapperLog(logWindow,100,@"Got a sandbox bookmark for %@",drive1SandboxBookmark);
```

I am getting Bad Exe access from this function, seemingly for no reason. It sometimes now is even doing this where the for mat string is just a string, no arguments... totally stumped:

```
void dapperLog(logWindowController *controller,int level,NSString *format, ...) {

    if(logLevel<level)return;
    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, format);
    if(!format)return;
    NSLog(@"%@",format);

    NSMutableString * message = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:format
                                                              arguments:argumentList];
    va_end(argumentList);
    if(currentRunningOSVersion<100900){
        NSLog(@"%@",message);
    return;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How is `drive1SandboxBookmark` defined?

Comment: does `drive1SandboxBookmark.description` work fine?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get an exception if the first item in `format` contains a placeholder (e.g. `%@`) but there is no corresponding argument. Btw: You don't need *mutable* String at all.

Comment: In the example shown, there is a single argument which is non null as per the calling line. Its an nsstring in fact... Lets assume it is somehow nil when it arrives, i wonder whats happening between the call and the function executing.

Comment: Strictly spoken a `va_list` is not **one** string, it's a comma separated list of strings. Just make sure that the number of placeholders match the number of arguments.

Comment: They do. Something else is going on here, i may have to clear some build caches